# "Den" oder "an den"?

Tags: dative, article, standard-german

Welcher Satz ist richtig?

> Die Produkte, die Sie an den Organisationen anbieten

oder

> Die Produkte, die Sie den Organisationen anbieten

Und wieso?

Further context: there is a company I want to apply for. They offer specific products to other companies and I want to say: Die Produkte, die Sie "an" den Organisationen anbieten, haben mein Interesse geweckt. But i'm not sure if I should write it with "an" or without.

Comment: The meanings of these sentences are orthogonal, so we can't tell without further context, sorry.

Comment: Further context: there is a company I want to apply for. They offer specific products to other companies and I want to say: Die Produkte, die Sie "an" den Organisationen anbieten, haben mein Interesse geweckt. But i'm not sure if I should write it with "an" or without.

Comment: Then the second is the correct one (without "an")

Comment: Hi and welcome @Cicciopasticcio. Please take the [tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour) to become familiar with the usual practice of this site.

Comment: @Cicciopasticcio you should edit your question by including the clarification from your comment into the body of the question, in order to prevent it from being closed for "unclear what you're asking for". You can always edit your own post regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beide Satzteile sind richtig, bedeuten aber jeweils etwas anderes.

> Die Produkte, die Sie den Organisationen anbieten ...

Hier sind die Organisationen als Kunden anzusehen, denen jemand (*Sie*) Produkte anbietet.

> Die Produkte, die Sie an den Organisationen anbieten ...

Hier wird lediglich gesagt, dass jemand (*Sie*) irgendeinem Kunden Produkte anbietet, und die Organisationen sind zunächst einmal nur der Ort, an dem das stattfindet. Sie sind aber nicht zwangsläufig auch die Kunden. Das Beispiel ist ähnlich zu

- Die Produkte, die Sie *an/in Ihren Filialen* anbieten ...
- Die Produkte, die Sie *in unseren Online-Shops* anbieten ...
- Die Produkte, die Sie *auf den Wochenmärkten* anbieten ...